# Using a $_POST array with database rows

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

How do I add the `$_POST` array (each item) per each database row I have? I have a from which has various of fields, however only one of them can the user change, which in this case is the quantity.

The rows in this field is exact to the one used in the PHP file (ordered).

I've used the `$_POST` array like so: `<input type="text" name = "quantity[]">`

Now, I want to show the same information as the user is shown (same rows), on the PHP side.

Here I have

```
if (is_array($_POST['quantity']) || is_object($_POST['quantity'])) {
     foreach($_POST['quantity']as $key=>$value) {
           $sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM info WHERE user_id = " . $user_id . " ORDER BY name ASC";
          foreach($dbq->query($sqlquery) as $row) {
               $message .= $row['name'] . $row['description'] . $row['amount'] . $value;
                echo $message;
           }
     }
}
```

Now the whole thing works as intended, expect that it loops twice. So each row is shown twice, and the quantity in the row is incorrect for half of them. If I have two rows, it will echo out four and only two of those will have the correct quantity, the other two will have the quantity value swapped around.

[image: Problem in question]

As shown in that picture, you can see the last value (2, 2, 15, 15) the values do not represent the correct row. The correct order should be (2, 15, 2, 15) as the rows are looped twice - which of course is not intended.

Comment: So on the HTML that's being submitted, how many `<input name="quantity[]" />` do you have?

Comment: Why are you testing `is_object()`? `$_POST` parameters will never be objects -- they're either strings or arrays.

Comment: @miken32 One per row. The rows are fetched from SQL database.

Comment: @Barmar I saw it somewhere on SO, that you should always test for it, so I blindly added it to my code. Didn't really change anything however.

Comment: For each quantity in the input, you're printing every row that the query returns. Why don't you expect duplicates?

Comment: @miken32 No, that's another PHP page. I only have it inside the function as shown in the code.

Comment: @Barmar Because I'm using the same query as fetched for the form page, so there should be no duplicates if they show the same data.

Comment: Depending on how `$user_id` is set you might be open to SQL injections. You should use parameterized queries.

Comment: Thanks Ryan! The var_dump for $_POST shows exactly what I would expect it to, an array with two values in this case (both strings, if that matter): 2 and 15.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your form so that the `quantity` field is something like this:

```
<input type="text" name="quantity[<?php echo $row['info_id']; ?>]">
```

Replace `info_id` with the actual name of the database column that refers to the item displayed in the form. Then when you process the form, you can use that

```
if (is_array($_POST['quantity'])) {
    foreach($_POST['quantity']as $key=>$value) {
        $sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM info WHERE user_id = " . $user_id . " AND id = " . $key . " ORDER BY name ASC";
        $row = $dbq->query($sqlquery);
        $message .= $row['name'] . $row['description'] . $row['amount'] . $value;
        echo $message;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if you really need the `user_id` test in the `SELECT` query, the `id` condition may be enough. But that depends on the details of your database.

Comment: Thanks, however now it shows this: https://imgur.com/2OdG42Y - I would like it to only show one row (from the SQL DB + then add the value to it, which is the $_POST value (amount), and in the end, echo it all out.

Comment: How are the rows in the form related to the database rows? The query doesn't use anything from the form.

Comment: The question says **The correct order should be (2, 15, 2, 15)**. Isn't that what my answer produces?

Comment: They're not, however I want the information shown here: https://imgur.com/djuYuKm - to be the same as shown in the $message, where $value from the user input is now included.
I phrased myself wrong when I said the correct order, however that was the correct order for that specific example.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar! This seems to work. I'll report back, if it doesn't work as intended, however thank you very much!
Edit: Not sure if relevant or not to your answer, but I had to change the $ row = $dbq->query.... to fetch_row_assoc, as query was complaining about "Cannot use object of type PDOStatement as array"

Comment: I have now tested this code more thoroughly, and it's working as it should. Thanks again @Barmar :)